# Do One-year MS/MEng Programs Prefer Candidates With Research Experience?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, research-undergraduate

I am a first-year undergraduate student studying mechanical engineering in the U.S. I want to either do the 5-year BS/MS program at my university, or - preferably - do a 1-year non-thesis MS or MEng degree from a top university such as MIT, directly after undergrad. I am already in a design team as well as Engineers Without Borders, and as such my schedule is quite full already. Research is interesting to me but not as interesting as my current extra-curriculars, and I would have to give up at least one of those or get worse grades in order to pursue undergraduate research.

I was reading an article written by an MIT student that said graduate programs look for undergraduate research experience when considering candidates, and strongly prefer candidates that have some, but don't really care about any of your extra-curriculars. However, this was discusssing 2-year MS degrees with a thesis. Since I'm only planning on doing a 1-year non-thesis degree I'd like to know whether it would be worth it to pursue undergraduate research, or whether it won't make much of a difference to my chances of being accepted into a 1-year masters program.

Comment: Why narrow so early on a 1 year MS? The actual decision point for you is years away. Yes, research is a positive thing. And "extra curriculars" mean almost nothing for grad school unless they are field related.

Comment: @Buffy I may change my mind, but I currently think that a 1-year is better for my needs than a 2-year because I am doing engineering and don't plan on working in research. Also, my extracurriculars (especially my design team) are related to my degree (that's kind of the purpose of a design team).